# How to pass dynamically created input values through POST variables

Tags: php, mysql

I will be brief.
I have this:

functions.php

```
function consulta($sql){
    $consulta = mysql_query($sql, $GLOBALS['conexion']) or die (mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($consulta) == 0){
        return -1;
    }else if (mysql_num_rows($consulta) == 1){
        $fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta);
        return $fila;
    }else{
        while($fila = mysql_fetch_array($consulta)){
            $lista[] = $fila;
        }
        return $lista;
    }
}
```

formgenerator.php

```
$art_ptes = consulta("SELECT * FROM articulos WHERE autorizacion = '0'");
echo "<form action='../private/control_insercion.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<input type='hidden' name='es_autorizacion' value='ok' />";
echo "<table id='aut_ptes'> 
    <tr><th colspan='8'>Autorizaciones pendientes</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Fecha</th><th>Título</th><th>Categoría</th><th>Artículo</th>     <th>Autor</th><th colspan='3'>Sanción</th></tr>";
if($art_ptes !== -1){
    if(is_array($art_ptes[0])){
        for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($art_ptes) ; $i++) {
            echo "<tr><td>".$art_ptes[$i][1]."</td> <td>".$art_ptes[$i][2]."</td><td>".$art_ptes[$i][3]."</td><td>".substr($art_ptes[$i][4], 0, 140)."<a href='#'>...ver</a></td><td>".$art_ptes[$i][5]."</td><td>AUT: <input name='autorizar".$i."' value='aut' type='radio' /></td><td>DEN: <input name='autorizar".$i."' value='den' type='radio' /></td><td>PTE: <input name='autorizar".$i."' value='pte' type='radio' checked='checked'/></td></tr>";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='id".$i."' value='".$art_ptes[$i][0]."' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='titulo".$i."' value='".$art_ptes[$i][2]."' />";
            echo "<input type='hidden' name='autor".$i."' value='".$art_ptes[$i][5]."' />";
        }
        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><input type='submit' value='Enviar!' /></td></tr>";
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td>".$art_ptes[1]."</td><td>".$art_ptes[2]."</td><td>".$art_ptes[3]."</td><td>".substr($art_ptes[4], 0, 140)."<a href='#'>...ver</a></td></td><td>".$art_ptes[5]."</td><td>AUT: <input name='autorizar' value='aut' type='radio' /></td><td>DEN: <input name='autorizar' value='den' type='radio' /></td><td>PTE: <input name='autorizar' value='pte' type='radio' checked='checked'/></td></tr>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$art_ptes[0]."' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='titulo' value='".$art_ptes[2]."' />";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='autor' value='".$art_ptes[5]."' />";
        echo "<tr><td colspan='8'><input type='submit' value='Enviar!' /></td></tr>";
    }
} else {
    echo "<tr><td colspan='8'>SIN REGISTROS</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>

    </form>";
```

control_insercion.php

```
/* ...more irrelevant code precedes */
} else if (isset($_POST['es_autorizacion']) and $_POST['es_autorizacion'] == 'ok') {

    $emails_den = array();
    $emails_aut = array();

    if(!isset($_POST['autorizar'])){
        $i = 0;
        while(isset($_POST['autorizar'.$i]) and $_POST['autorizar'.$i] == 'aut'){

            if($_POST['autorizar'.$i] == 'aut') {
                $consulta = ("UPDATE articulos SET autorizacion = '1' WHERE titulo = '".$_POST['titulo'.$i]."' AND autor = '".$_POST['autor'.$i]."' AND id = '".$_POST['id'.$i]."';"); 
                $resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
                $email = consulta("SELECT email FROM autores WHERE autor = '".$_POST['autor'.$i]."';");
                $emails_aut[] = $email;

            }else if($_POST['autorizar'.$i] == 'den') {
                $consulta = ("DELETE FROM articulos WHERE id = '".$_POST['id'.$i]."';");
                $resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
                $email = consulta("SELECT email FROM autores WHERE autor = '".$_POST['autor'.$i]."';");
                $emails_den[] = $email;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    } else {
        if($_POST['autorizar'] == 'aut') {
                $consulta = ("UPDATE articulos SET autorizacion = '1' WHERE titulo = '".$_POST['titulo']."' AND autor = '".$_POST['autor']."' AND id = '".$_POST['id']."';"); 
                $resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
                $email = consulta("SELECT email FROM autores WHERE autor = '".$_POST['autor']."'");
                $emails_aut[] = $email;

            } else if ($_POST['autorizar'] == 'den') {
                $consulta = ("DELETE FROM articulos WHERE id = '".$_POST['id']."';");
                $resultado = mysql_query($consulta, $conexion) or die(mysql_error());
                $email = consulta("SELECT email FROM autores WHERE autor = '".$_POST['autor']."';");
                $emails_den[] = $email;
            }

    }
    $uno = serialize($emails_den); //checking whther everything went right//
    $dos = serialize($emails_aut);
    header("location../public/pruebas.php?resultado=".$uno."&resultado2=".$dos."");
}
```

It consists is consulting the users articles that are waiting for the administrator authorization.

In formgenerator.php a dynamic table is generated with all these articles.

The administrator click on authorized or denied at each article row.

POST variables pass to the processor php page where the articles should be aupdated to authirized or deleted in the corresponding mysql table.

I ask for some help as the final result of all these scripts is that it returns the control_insercion.php page blank. Even the header is not executed.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You probably have some error, may be in DB or in PHP. Have you checked the errors log from apache?

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in your header function.

```
header("location../public/pruebas.php?resultado=".$uno."&resultado2=".$dos."");
```

The above syntax is missing the colon after the location. It should be

```
header("location:../public/pruebas.php?resultado=".$uno."&resultado2=".$dos."");
```

Comment: Thanks!! I already saw it. Thanks again for dedicating your time at this issue!!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!!!

sorry for wasting the time of those whos where trying to solve it for me!!!!

After after reviewing it over and over I realized that i did two dummy mistakes. First at the first line of the control_insercion.php code: ... and $_POST['es_autorizacion'] == 'ok' ... shoulden't be there. I erased it as this condition is already expressed below at the if statements. The second mistake is at the last line of the  same page. The word location lacks a colon (punctuation mark)
I have to give up drinking wine while coding ;=)
At least I hope this issue help others to see how passing dynamyc data to other php page.
Greetings!